# PayPal Orders v2 create returning 422 (Unprocessable Entity) when passing amount discount

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the [PayPal REST SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/) client side JavaScript to [create an order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create) and I have the below code:

```
    paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
        size: 'responsive',
        layout: 'vertical'
    },
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
        return actions.order.create({
            intent: 'CAPTURE',
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    currency_code: 'AUD',
                    value: '70.00',
                    breakdown: {
                        discount: {
                            currency_code: 'AUD',
                            value: '5.00'
                        }
                    }
                },
                description: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
                // custom_id: '',
            }]
        });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        });
    }
}).render('.purchase-modal');

}
```

This returns the aforementioned error and status code [422 (Unprocessable Entity)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-responses/#http-status-codes).

This chunk of the code appears to be the problem, if it is removed the error goes away:

```
breakdown: {
    discount: {
        currency_code: 'AUD',
        value: '5.00'
    }
}
```

I checked and this appears to be valid?

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: stumbled upon [this](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/Applying-Discounts-to-Payment-Orders/td-p/1761738#) might help - it seems you need to specify: `"breakdown": { "item_total": {` and `"discount": {`

Comment: @jibsteroos Yeah I noticed that but I didn't think it was required as it states "Required if the request includes purchase_units[].items[].unit_amount" - which I haven't included, but I will give it a shot anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to read the whole JSON response error message from the JavaScript console or browser Network tab.

```
{
   "name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
   "details":[
      {
         "field":"/purchase_units/0/amount/value",
         "value":"70.00",
         "issue":"AMOUNT_MISMATCH",
         "description":"Should equal item_total + tax_total + shipping + handling + insurance - shipping_discount - discount."
      }
   ],
   "message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
   "debug_id":"3c22979dc723a",
   "links":[
      {
         "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-AMOUNT_MISMATCH",
         "rel":"information_link",
         "method":"GET"
      }
   ]
}
```

Note particularly the message in "description".

So, there you have it. If the specified total value is `70` and the discount is `5`, you need to tell PayPal what the things were that added up to be `75`(!) before such a "discount" was applied. Otherwise this "discount" value is meaningless by itself, PayPal doesn't know what to do with it, and the 422 Unprocessable error ensues to remove any ambiguity about the situation.

---

### Side note...

You aren't using the "REST SDK" here, since that's specific to the server side. Client side code is the JavaScript SDK.  If you do want to use the compatible REST APIs for a server-side integration (recommended), implement two routes on your server, one for "Set Up Transaction" and one for "Capture Transaction", documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Then change your JavaScript code to the server demo's: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , linked up to those two routes of yours

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Yeah, I didn't see the JSON in the console, but you're right, it was in the network tab. Good point about REST too, it's all just kinda bundled under the REST section so please excuse the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, the account needs to be verified properly.

Please check if you have any limitations by clicking this URL (make sure you are logged in first):

https://www.paypal.com/disputes/

If you have any limitations, you will need to solve it all.
https://www.paypal.com/restore/dashboard

Comment: Confirmed. I sadly did not have any response body. After I logged in to Paypal, I got an email that I confimed my phone number (again). Afterwords it worked again. Wish they would not break the pay process for this or inform me before they cut the wire.